# How can I import a module from memory - not from the module files?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, import, amazon-efs

I am importing Torch in both the main file and a submodule I load - loading from a mounted EFS block on AWS.

Since the EFS block has limited throughput and the main runs only once while the submodule runs many times, can I avoid the disk load by using the Torch loaded into memory from the main module?

Comment: Regular `import`s already only load a module once in a Python process. You don't need to worry about having multiple modules import the same module.

Comment: I wonder why the EFS block would be hitting throughput cap after a few invokes then. Does mounting count as reading the whole block?